# Run git command without sudo doesn't work on applications

Tags: git, intellij-idea, push, sudo

i have a problem with git... from any application(Intellij, SmartGit, STS) when run git command without sudo doesn't work... I can't push or pull branches. Intellij with VCS run git commands without sudo and can't integrate with my repository.

Intellij command Line:

```
[jnieto@localhost apiconsola]$ git push origin API#test
fatal: repository 'http://jonatan@localhost:17990/scm/cnt/apiconsola.git/' not found
[jnieto@localhost apiconsola]$ sudo git push origin API#test
[sudo] password for jnieto: 
Password for 'http://jonatan@localhost:17990': 
Everything up-to-date
```

Thanks for all,
Jonatan.

Comment: Check permissions for the `.git` directory and its members.

Comment: Permissions are correct.